# The asymptote to the graph?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

$$f(x)=\frac{x-\sqrt{|x^2+x|}}{x}$$

I found that limit at $-\infty$ is $2$ and limit at $+\infty$ is $0$.
The limit to $0$ positive is minus infinity: $\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{x-\sqrt{|x^2+x|}}{x} = -\infty$.

Comment: What exactly do you ask?

Comment: What is the asymptote to zero negative? I suppose is minus infinite, but I don't know to demonstrate it.

Comment: I still not sure I understand, you calculate the limits, so you have $f$ is asymptotic to $y=0$ from the right, to $y=2$ from the left and $x=0$ at $0$

Comment: No, please read carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Write your term in the form

$$1-\sqrt{\left|1+\frac{1}{x}\right|}$$ this tends to $-\infty$ if $x$ tends to $0^+$

Answer (score 1):

There is a vertical asymptote at the line $x=0$.  Like you stated $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) \rightarrow -\infty.$